# Proving ker inequality of two transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ S, T: V \rightarrow V $

prove: $\ max \{\dim \ker T,\dim \ker S \} \le \dim \ker (TS) \le \dim \ker T + \dim \ker S $

I have no clue to prove it. Couldn't understand the solution given as well..

Comment: Please provide the solution and what specific point(s) you don't understand in it.

Comment: $\ dimImTS \le min \{ dimImT, dimImS \} $ - I couldn't prove it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose V is finite-dimensional vector space and S,T are linear operators.

If $S(x)=0$ then $TS(x)=0$. Hence kerS $\subseteq $ kerTS .

Now $ S(V) \subseteq V $ so $ T(S(V))=TS(V) \subseteq T(V) $ so  dim Im $TS \leq$ dim Im $T$ . So  dim ker T $\leq$ dim ker TS

This proves the first inequality.

Let $U: ker(TS) \to kerT$ be defined by $U(x)=S(x)$. Then $U$ is linear transformation. And dim ker (TS) = dim ker (U) + rank (U) . Note that ker(U)=ker(S) and rank(U) $\le$ dim ker (T). This proves the second claim.

Comment: Thanks! much cleaner answer than I got!

Comment: Couldn't get on my own the last inequality. can you elaborate please?